# ¿Por qué no si inicializa la sesión en php?

Tags: php, php7

Cuando realizo las pruebas de forma local todo funciona bien, hasta que lo subo al servidor.

Tengo una carpeta de templates donde generalmente coloco el menu de la aplicación y abro una sesión, también en el login abro una sesión si los datos son correctos.

Pero al iniciar sesión me aparecen estos errores.

Warning: Undefined global variable $_SESSION in /home/innehkwa/public_html/SistemaLlaves/Controller/ComponentesController.php on line 4

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/innehkwa/public_html/SistemaLlaves/Controller/ComponentesController.php on line 4

Por lo que la sesión no se está iniciando, pero me gustaría saber que estpy haciendo mal.

Este es el código que uso para el login,

```
function IniciarSesion(){

        if(isset($_POST["btnLogin"]))
        {
            $email = $_POST["txtEmail"];
            $password = $_POST["txtPassword"];
            $resultado = ValidarIngresoModel($email);
        
            if($resultado -> num_rows > 0)
            {
                session_start();

                $item = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
                if(password_verify($password, $item['PASS_USR'])){
                    
                    $_SESSION["NombreUsuario"] = $item["USUARIO_USR"];
                    $_SESSION["RolUsuario"] = $item["ID_ROL_FK"];
                    $_SESSION["IdUsuario"] = $item["ID_USUARIO"];
        
                    echo '<script>
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: "¡Haz iniciado sesión correctamente!",
                        text: "¡Dirigete al inicio!",
                        imageUrl: "https://innehkwan.com/SistemaLlaves/img/combate.jpg",
                        imageWidth: 550,
                        imageHeight: 400,
                        imageAlt: "Custom image",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
                        cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
                        confirmButtonText: "¡Ir al inicio!"
                      }).then((result) => {
                        if (result.isConfirmed) {
                            window.location.href = "https://innehkwan.com/SistemaLlaves/View/inicio.php";
                        }
                      });
                        </script>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Y en el template tengo lo siguiente,

```
include_once '../Controller/LoginController.php';
include_once '../Controller/ComponentesController.php';

function nav(){
    
    session_start();
    ValidarSesion();

    $usuario = $_SESSION["NombreUsuario"];

    echo 
    '
    <nav class="sb-topnav navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <!-- Navbar Brand-->
        <a class="navbar-brand ps-3" href="inicio.php">Sistema de llaves</a>
        <!-- Sidebar Toggle-->
        <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm order-1 order-lg-0 me-4 me-lg-0" id="sidebarToggle" href="#!"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
        <!-- Navbar Search
        <form class="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ms-auto me-0 me-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search for..." aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNavbarSearch" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </form>-->
        <!-- Navbar-->
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto me-0 me-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">'.$usuario.'<i class="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Ajustes</a></li>
                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                    <li>
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            <input type="submit" value="Cerrar Sesión" name="btnCerrarSesion" class="btn btn-default">
                        <form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    ';
}
```

Además en ComponentesController hago 2 funciones donde se validan las sesiones

```
    function ValidarSesion()
    {       
        if($_SESSION["RolUsuario"] == null)
        {
            session_destroy();
            header("Location: login.php");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `session_start();` debe ir al inicio del código... incluso antes de incluir los demás archivos

Comment: Sabes si debe de ir presente en todos los archivos? Aunque esté presente en las plantillas?

Comment: Por lo poco que veo, parece que no estuvieras usando ningún framework, si es así, deberías incluirlo en cada archivo php en el cual quieras usar la sesión. Es decir, si por ejemplo tienes un index.php, un login.php y un content.php... y cada uno se ejecuta por aparte, deberías incluir esa linea en cada uno de ellos

Comment: Voy a intentarlo, eso cuenta solo para las vistas? o tambien el model y el controller?

Comment: Depende... del orden en el que se carguen los archivos

Comment: Tengo esta noticia, cuando abro la sesión en todas las pantallas Notice: session_start(): Ignoring session_start() because a session is already active in C:\xampp\htdocs\SistemallavesProd\SistemaLlaves\Controller\LoginController.php on line 2

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139103/discussion-between-pipe-and-ivan-coto-jimenez).